# How to ship luggage from EWR to a local address in NJ

Tags: air-travel, luggage, ewr

I want to know if there are any luggage shipping services at EWR that, upon flight arrival, could ship a few suitcases to a local address?

Answer (score 3):

United does this at Newark, if you are on a United flight: See https://www.maketraveleasier.com/united

You can also skip the airport all together and have shipped door to door with something like this. With enough advanced notice, this can be as little as $30 coast to coast and you save the checked-bags fee (if applicable).

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of this service. However this is only for domestic flights. Mine is international.